# python __setattr__ to act like __getattr__

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a class that contains a dictionary, i use `__getattr__(key)` to get nicer access to the `dictionary[key]` now i would like to be able to set things in the dictionary with the same access style.

```
Class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.props = {"name":name}

    def __getattr__(self, attribute):
        return self.props[attribute]
```

This is so i can access it in this way

```
f = foo("test")
print f.name
```

I would like the ability to set the attributes aswell, however using **setattr** is proving problematic due to it being called before anything else fails. Is there a way to make it act like **getattr**?

Comment: No need to reinvent this one, a bunch does what you need: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bunch/1.0.1 you can refer to its impl if it does not actually do what you want https://github.com/dsc/bunch/blob/master/bunch/__init__.py

Comment: Thanks for the help, it doesn't actually do exactly what i need, but it seems to have the part i need.

Comment: no problem, that is why I updated the comment because I realized you probably made a nice [MCVE] and then I assumed that was your whole problem. Glad I helped.

Answer (score 1):

`__setattr__` is fine, but you need to protect yourself from case when `__setattr__` is called before `self.props` is set (`RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`)

```
class foo(object):
    # List of properties which are not stored in the props dict
    __slots__ = ('props', 'other_property')

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.props = {"name":name}
        self.other_property = 2

    def __getattr__(self, attribute):
        return self.props[attribute]

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name in self.__slots__:
            super(foo, self).__setattr__(name, value)
        else:
            self.props[name] = value

f = foo("name")
print f.name
f.value = 2
f.name = "TEST"
print f.value
print f.props
```

Comment: Hi, so i tested it out, but the problem appears when foo has more than just self.props. For example if i have self.test = "test" in it, altering it later with f.test = "foobar" will just add "test" to f.props

Comment: After hours of trial and error with help from your first answer, i managed to get it working how i wanted, although i will look into __slots__ as an alternative to my solution. Thank you for your help!